# miktex-makepk - PK font HieroB could not be created

Tags: miktex2.9, hieroglf

I am depressed, after trying to install HieroTeX with MikTex 2.9 and TeXnicenter for four weeks without succeeding. I installed hieroglf, it works perfectly, but has only 60 signs.
I followed the main advices, so I created a folder texmf-Local , throwed in  the content of HieroTex3.5 and Hiero-Type1.3.1.4 , put the axmf , mf and sty files where I think they belong, put that directory  texmf- local in the path searched by Miktex, updated map and file databases fo Miktex. Still the files can be compiled but Hiero fonts are not found. 
Te main errors I can detect from log are the following:
  " No file egypto.sty.tex found"
and 
"  "miktex-makepk - PK font HieroB could not be created." and similar for other fonts
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Download http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/hieroglyph/HieroType1-3.1.4.tgz
- Unpack it somewhere
- In the tar there is a texmf-folder, but it is in part wrong

  - move from the `dvips` folder the two map files to `fonts/map/pdftex`
  - delete the dvips folder (and the config.ps, at best it can do harm)
  - delete the pdftex folder and its content
  - from `fonts/type1` move all `.tfm` files into `fonts/tfm`
- go to the miktex console and register the `texmf` as a new root (in the settings tab):

[image]

Then you can try this document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfmapfile{=hierofonts.map}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}

{\font\test=HieroA \test \char 32}
\fonttable{HieroA}
\fonttable{HieroB}
\fonttable{HieroExt}

\end{document}
```

which gave me

[image]

You can find the names of the font in hierofonts.map. The diacr-fonts in the other map probably won't work, I found no tfm or source for them.

You can install the texmf of hierotex itself also by attaching in the miktex console, but I doubt that it still works, as the tfm of some fonts are missing here too, but as it requires to run an unknown application as preprocessor I didn't try.

Comment: thanks a lot. It works.  It gives an error if I try to compile with latex->ps->pdf but it is ok if you just go from Latex-> pdf and it is plenty for what I nedd.

Comment: Then now create in the texmf a folder miktex/config, add there a updmap.cfg with the content `Map hierofonts.map`. Go to the miktex console (user mode if you added the texmf as user), refresh first the file name database and then the font map files (both is in the tasks menu). Then it should work without the \pdfmapfile command and also with latex+dvips.

Comment: I still have a ( solvable ) problem, confronting with Gardiner's list of hieroglyph as for example B 58 in Gardiner's list is the "b" leg+foot but you get the same symbol with HieroD char 92. I printed rhe complete list of the actual symbols and I am crossing to gardiner's list. Thank again forthe big help you gave me